# Execute a query but get an error if it is in waiting state for too long

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Is there a way for an application to send a query to a database but have the database terminate the query and throw an error if the query waits too long? Something like:

```
WAIT FOR CAST('1 min' AS INTERVAL) <your query here>
```

If value of `waiting` in `pg_stat_activity` has been `true` for any longer than the given interval, the database should cancel the query and return an error, which would be interpreted by the application as an `Exception`.

Does something like this exist? Or is there any workaround (preferably written in Java) that can achieve the same effect?

A particular use case I'm targeting is this (in a *simplified* form of Java code):

```
try {
    statement.executeUpdate("WAIT FOR CAST('30 sec' AS INTERVAL) TRUNCATE my_table");
    //TRUNCATE may wait if other processes are accessing the table,
    //example a backup process that has locked the table.
} catch (WaitTimeoutException wte) {
    statement.executeUpdate("DELETE FROM my_table");
}
```

The idea is to preferably do `TRUNCATE` as this is much faster, but if the query ends up waiting for too long, then I should fall back to `DELETE` instead to get the job done.

This could also be used to time queries out in other use cases, where you don't want the application waiting forever. Instead, the application can detected the condition of *"waiting too long"* and act appropriately (such as alerting the user or trying again after logging).

Comment: have you tried [statement.setQueryTimeout(30)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setQueryTimeout(int))

Comment: I get the impression that Postgres has poor support for `setQueryTimeout` but I will give it a try.

Comment: At the very worst you could set the socketTimeout that uses the OS so should work.

Comment: Does `setQueryTimeout` cancel an actual **executing** query that's just taking longer than the timeout? While I would want it to cancel a **waiting** query, I don't want it to cancel one that's not waiting but actually executing. I'm highly suspicious due to the documentation *"Sets the number of seconds the driver will wait for a Statement object to execute"* as it implies that this is the driver waiting for DBMS to finish executing within the timeout, not the DBMS waiting for the table to be freed for access. **What I'm looking for is the latter case.**

Comment: Are you aware that if a transaction uses a table in such a way that it needs to be locked, another transaction on the same table may end up waiting for the first transaction to be done? I am not talking about stopping the truncate halfway. I'm talking about automatically cancelling a truncate that hasn't even started yet, but is waiting for another transaction to complete. With a timeout it should not wait any longer than that. But if there's no waiting the timeout is not applicable at all. Please look into what `pg_stat_activity.waiting is true` means.

Comment: SET statement_timeout TO 1000; http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-STATEMENT

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SET lock_timeout TO 1000; OR
SET statement_timeout TO 1000;
```

More information at:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-CLIENT-STATEMENT

Comment: I believe this also has the same problem as the other suggestion. It will abort any statement taking longer than the timeout **regardless** of whether is it executing or waiting. But what about `lock_timeout (integer)`?

Comment: Sorry missed that detail. lock_timeout looks like it might do what you want, test her out and see for sure.